# How can i get Id item number in entity data model

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

i'm trying to check the login information ,,, and get the item Id if they are correct ,,, Otherwise show error entry message 
my code is:

```
var getid = from user in db.tables
            where user.name == tbusername.Text && user.password == tbpassword.Text
            select user.Id;

c = Int32.Parse(getid);
```

but the vs say there's an error at `c = Int32.Parse(getid);` What's wrong?

Comment: don't mind ,,, like "username or password is incorrect"

Comment: `"username or password is incorrect"` is not your only troubles

Comment: nope ,,, i can't check whether the username and password are correct or no and get id if they are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant convert a list to an integer. `Where` returns a collection, (or said better an [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)). You are pushing a list of something into a space (Int32.Parse) that only wants a 1 of something.

Also if your Id is an int, you shouldn't have to parse it

**Example**

```
var getid = (from user in db.tables
            where user.name == tbusername.Text && user.password == tbpassword.Text
            select user.Id).FirstOrDefault();

// or
var getid = db.tables.Where(user => user.name == tbusername.Text && user.password == tbpassword.Text)
                     .Select(user => user.Id)
                     .FirstOrDefault();

if(getid == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Oh nooez!!!");
    return;
}

MessageBox.Show("You is id : " + getid );
```

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence contains no elements.

[Enumerable.Where Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

**Return Value**

> Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable An
>   IEnumerable that contains elements from the input sequence that
>   satisfy the condition.